# Add <span> after all starting anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to add a span after all opening anchor tags no matter what is inside the anchor. I'm working in a CMS so `$content` will hold all my links and is a long HTML string.

I first tried `str_replace()` but it apparently doesn't use wildcards.

```
$content = str_replace( '<a href="%">', '<a href="%"><span class="fa"></span>', $content );
```

So then I tried `preg_replace()` but I not only do not know enough regex to do it, but I don't necessarily replace the things I find but instead find what I want to find then append the `<span>`. What is a good function to Find a my beginning anchors then append a `<span>` or any other data after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
$content = preg_replace('/<a (.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/', '<a $1 ><span class="fa"></span>$2</a>', $content);
```

`(.*?)` is get anything, then the `$1` corresponds to replacing the first `(.*?)` back in. Therefore the second occurrence is then placed where `$2` is.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this, good time saver for me, I used it to add some blank spans in just after a label opening tag for gravity forms. 

    $content = preg_replace('/<label (.*?)>(.*?)<\/label>/', '<label $1 ><span></span>$2</label>', $content);